# Issue with %in% in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get all sentences from a dataframe containing specific words into a new dataframe. I don't really know how to do this, but the first step I tried was to check if a word is in the column.

```
> "quality" %in% df$text[2]
[1] FALSE
> df$text[2]
[1] "Audio quality is definitely good"
```

Why is the output false?

Also, do you have any suggestion on how to create my new dataframe? I'd like to, as an example, have a dataframe with all words containing c("word1","word2").

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a fixed match.  If we need to partially match, use `grepl`

```
grepl("quality", df$text[2])
```

If we are doing this to check if there are any 'quality' in the column, wrap with `any`

```
any(grepl("quality", df$text))
```

For multiple elements, `paste` them together with `collapse = "|"`

```
v1 <- c("word1","word2")
any(grepl(paste(v1, collapse="|"), df$text))
```

---

According to `?%in%`

> %in% is currently defined as
>
> "%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0

where `match` matches the string based on an exact match.